# 2D Image Rigging/Warping/Skeleton tool with an API for characters limbs control

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, image

I am looking for a tool/library preferably in Python that can warp a given image with some described points/area i.e limbs of a character which can then be morphed into a new position using another set of instructions about a new pose, I have searched but only found tools like Adobe Character and wallpaperengine.io which do fulfil the input/output I want but they lack the API system with which I can automate it.